# How can one derive Stokes lines of the Stokes phenomenon of asymptotics from a differential equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, special-functions

Is there a standard technique to calculate Stokes lines and anti-Stokes lines of the Stokes phenomenon of asymptotics for a function defined as the general solution to a differential equation without directly solving the differential equation?

For example, consider the differential equation
\begin{gather}
\frac{dz}{d\phi} = \lambda e^{i \phi} z - 1
\end{gather}
where $\lambda$ and $\phi$ are real, but $z$ is complex.  This has solution
\begin{gather}
z_A(\phi) = A e^{- i \lambda \exp(i \phi)} + i e^{- i \lambda \exp(i \phi)} \operatorname{Ei} \left( i \lambda e^{i \phi} \right)
\end{gather}
where $A$ is a constant and $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the exponential integral.  I therefore conclude that the general solution for $z$ in the above differential equation has Stokes lines that correspond to the Stokes lines for $\operatorname{Ei}(i \lambda e^{i \phi})$, viz., $\phi = \pi / 2$ and $\phi = - \pi / 2$. This is all very well, but consider that I now generalise the above differential equation in some way, e.g., write $\lambda = \lambda(z)$, add a term proportional to $z^2$, or do something even more exotic, such that I can no longer find a solution.  Can one nevertheless determine the Stokes lines and anti-Stokes lines that a general solution has?

Comment: One can do this for linear differential equations. For nonlinear equations it looks impossible in general since the local asymptotic behaviour in this case will depend on the initial conditions.

Comment: Is then a Stokes line ill-defined for a differential equation? And by extension, does it then not make sense to speak of a Stokes line in the dynamical structure of a dynamical variable?

Comment: I don't understand how one could define it for a nonlinear ODE (the asymptotics of its solutions can be, and in general is, more complicated than the asymptotics of solutions of linear ODEs around irregular singularities). And even in those cases where one could speak about Stokes lines, their positions may depend not only on the equation (as in the linear case) but also on the initial conditions.